# WCSession activateSession exc_bad_access crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, watchos-2, wcsession

I have trouble with `WCSession activateSession`.
I added this code in my `viewDidLoad` method, and it's crashing at `activateSession` call. sendMessage is also crashing.

```
if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
    [WCSession defaultSession].delegate = self;
    [[WCSession defaultSession] activateSession];
}
```

I though that problem my be with thread, but I debug it and these calls on main thread.

any idea what can be the problem?

here is crash log:

thread #1: tid = 0x10aa81, 0x0000000110917817 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 23, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x408f59958d3)
    frame #0: 0x0000000110917817 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 23
    frame #1: 0x000000010be8fd1c myApp`+[CRWCSessionDelegateProxy performSwizzledWCSessionActivateSession:] + 62
    frame #2: 0x000000010be8f869 myApp`+[CRWCSessionDelegateProxy activateSessionForWCSession:dispatch:] + 72
    frame #3: 0x000000010be8ec64 myApp`__72+[CRWCSessionDelegateProxy swizzleWCSessionActivateSessionWithDispatch:]_block_invoke + 37
  * frame #4: 0x000000010bd6c4e4 myApp`-[FPMAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:](self=0x00007ff588d06800, _cmd="application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:", application=0x00007ff588c00850, launchOptions=0x0000000000000000) + 5236 at FPMAppDelegate.m:188
    frame #5: 0x000000010e50d1f1 UIKit`-[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 272
    frame #6: 0x000000010e50e397 UIKit`-[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3415
    frame #7: 0x000000010e514cc6 UIKit`-[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1760
    frame #8: 0x000000010e511e7b UIKit`-[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    frame #9: 0x0000000113203754 FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 192
    frame #10: 0x0000000113203ac2 FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    frame #11: 0x0000000110db4a31 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    frame #12: 0x0000000110daa95c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    frame #13: 0x0000000110da9e13 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 867
    frame #14: 0x0000000110da9828 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    frame #15: 0x000000010e5117cd UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 402
    frame #16: 0x000000010e516610 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 171
    frame #17: 0x000000010bcdc8cf myApp`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff540ca3c0) + 111 at main.m:16
    frame #18: 0x0000000111ab292d libdyld.dylib`start + 1

Comment: Share the console log. your code is fine.

Comment: Is there any other piece of code in your AppDelegate 's didfinishlaunchoption method?

Comment: yes, there is bunch of code. but i think problem is with session.delegate.
i have move this code to init and viewdidload, and the same crash happens

Comment: The above code is fine.You are targeting watche os 2 , you have implemented all the required things. Did you run your app with above code commented out ?

Comment: this is happens when i'm runing ios app. on watchkit it works fine.

Comment: I never encounter this issue in my app. neither if i run my target iOS app only. Can u share ur code.?

Comment: The call stack method names (such as `performSwizzledWCSessionActivateSession`) makes it sound like you are doing some swizzling; my guess is something is going wrong there. What is the goal with the swizzling you are doing?

Comment: I'm not doing swizzling in my project. 
I think this is can be thread problem, i created new project and copy past the WCSession code and it works fine. 
what is strange to me is the session.delegate (see in this link: http://imgur.com/AfDmDZv)
any idea what is CRWCSessionDelegateProxy?

Answer (score 3):

I have Crittercism framwork in my app. Once i commented this line in my app delegate method all works fine.

```
[Crittercism enableWithAppID:CRITTERCISM_APP_ID];
```

If you are using Cirttercism in your app, make sure to write this line `[[WCSession defaultSession] activateSession]` before Crittercism. 
Seems they have watch 2.0 support and that's the cause of conflict.

Comment: Man you saved my day!

Comment: This seems to be fixed in the latest crittercism sdk. I'm now on v5.6.2

Answer (score 1):

Your code must be called before

```
[Crittercism enableWithAppID:].
```